# Playing videos in UITableViewCell and make UITableview scroll smoothly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am using AVFoundation (`AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer`) for playing video within `UITableviewCell`.

I also have some labels and buttons in custom cell.

When I scroll my `tableview`, the scrolling is not so smooth and it stuck for some time when video (**that are viewable on the screen**) is about to play.

So how to play videos smoothly so that it doesn't affect the scrolling smoothness?

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about pausing the movies while you're scrolling, them resuming when your not scrolling?

Comment: I have done that functionality, when video is out of the visible screen ,video will stop play and when video come in visible screen, it will start to play.

Comment: No, while you're **scrolling**, it stops the video. When you're not scrolling, it plays the video.

Comment: I'm sure that it's a problem of reusable cell. Did you hide the video player from cell and test? Do you stream from network? If you're sure that the player cause this problem, you have to check this.

Comment: @theMonster - how would you implement pausing while scrolling?

Comment: @NiravPatel did you achieved the desired result ?